# Spring batch Parrall step

Tags: spring-batch

I have spring-batch job, where i need to pass as an input to the job a list of id's, I would want that from that list of id's to be able pass to a step that could run all of them in parrallel. As for now what I've accomplish is run multiple job instance in a threadpoolExecutor, that executes the job x number of time. This implies that it does single queries for all jobs. And we are talking about over 50 millions records. The records represents a timeseries @specific day a consumption. I need for an id and batchId aggregate by month and send this information to a broker.

- Reader -> reads from the database according to an id and a timestamps
  representing a time series.
- Processor -> PassThroughItemProcessor
- Writer -> Send to AMQP (aggregates the the list of items)

Is there any best practice you could provide me ?

---

According to the suggestions, this is how my partitioner looks like ;

```
@Override
public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int gridSize) {
    log.debug("START: Partition");

    Map<String, ExecutionContext> partitionMap = new HashMap<>();
    final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
    final AtomicInteger partitionerCounter = new AtomicInteger(0);
    Page<Integer> result = null;
    do {
        result = repository.findDistinctByBatchId(LocalDateTime.parse(batchId, AipForecastService.DEFAULT_DATE_TIME_FORMATTER), Optional.ofNullable(result)
                .map(Page::nextPageable)
                .orElse(PageRequest.of(0, 100000)));
        result
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(it -> counter.getAndIncrement() / 100))
                .values()
                .forEach(listOfInstallation -> {
                    ExecutionContext context = new ExecutionContext();
                    context.put("listOfInstallation", listOfInstallation);
                    partitionMap.put("partition" + partitionerCounter.incrementAndGet(), context);
                    log.debug("Adding to the partition map {}, listOfInstallation {}", partitionerCounter.get(), listOfInstallation);
                });
    } while (result.hasNext());

    log.debug("END: Created Partitions for installation job of size:{}", partitionMap.size());
    return partitionMap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> i need to pass as an input to the job a list of id's, I would want that from that list of id's to be able pass to a step that could run all of them in parrallel

You can partition that list and use a [partitioned step](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/scalability.html#partitioning) to process partitions in parallel.

> Is there any best practice you could provide me ?

If you choose the partitioned step route (which looks appropriate to me for your use case), I would recommend to not create a partition per id (unless you have a reasonable number of IDs). You can create for example a partition per range of IDs and make each worker step do the read/process/write logic you described which could be definitely done in parallel.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, when you Say "i would recommend to notre create a partition per ID unless you have reasonable number of IDs" does 240k sounds reasonable for you ? 240k represents the total number of ID from wich a timeseries is associate. Possible results could be 240k * 365 Days * 2 years = 262800000. Also i was wondering if you could provide a concrete example of how to use the partionner for both case you mentionned

Comment: Also need to keep in mind that my Writer have to send the aggregated data for a specific by YearMonth, therefore the payload sent to the Exchange has to represent a full YearMonth

Comment: 240k partitions is too high. So having a partition for each ID is not a good option for you. You can partition by range in that case. There is no best value for the number of partitions, but 100 is a good start I think. For examples, you can find one for local partitioning here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-samples#partitioning-sample and another one for remote partitioning here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-samples#remote-partitioning-sample

Comment: Hi, I've tried as you pointed out. Perhaps using the Default Implementation of the PartitionHandler, makes futureCalls and blocking with (.get()) until the query is all executors returned the rs. Isn't there a better way I could implement ?

Comment: I've paste the content of my implementation of the partitioner.